# How to reduce the usage of heavy bootstrap css in production?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I feel bootstrap is heavy to use in production which is using more bandwidth. is there way to short this issue ? I hope lot ways are there. As a new to development i had keen interest to know .. thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use following methodologies to improve site performance while you using bootstrap.

**Method 1 :** Use the minified versions of all the .css and .js

**Method 2 :** Use `gzip` compression to compress everything sent to client browsers

**Method 3 :** Use CDN , content delivery networks are really helping to serve commonly used `css` `js` contents. You can use one of the bootstrap cdn  instructed by Bootstrap itself  (https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/getting-started/)

```
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

**Method 4** You can customise using https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/customize/ . Here you can choose needed components. This will also improve performance

Answer (score 6):

You can download the [less files](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/) (scss files in v4) and build your own "bootstrap css" with parts you only need. Or you can customise it [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/customize/) if the "less" part is to complicated for you. As mentioned by Daren, make sure you use the minified version of it. Also a bit more friendly would be to use a CDN as that helps with browser caching.

Comment: The nice thing about the customized download page, is that it will also give you a 'config.json' file, so you can update again and again without clicking all those boxes, and keep your customized versions consistent.

Answer (score 3):

If you are not already, you should use the minified version of bootstrap (essentially it is the same as the normal bootstrap without any whitespaces/ spaces so the file size is smaller and it runs faster).